# Wrong constructor initialization

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor, initialization

Im' trying to initialize my "cl" class with that :

```
class Base
{
    Base(int x){}

private :
    Base(){}
};


class Test
{
public:
    Base cl(12);
};
```

But I get (with gcc) *error: expected identifier before numeric constant*
And I don't want to set the "Base" default constructor public

Any "workaround" ?

Comment: Are you trying to have the default `Test` instantiation have a public `cl` variable initialized with 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data-members cannot be initialized directly in class through a constructor call. Because of the **[Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)**<sup>1</sup>, your `c1` member is parsed as a function declaration. An incorrect declaration, albeit.

In C++03 and before, you would need to initialize your class through the initializer-list of the constructor:

```
class Test
{
    public:
        Test() : cl(21)
        //     ^^^^^^^^
        {};

        Base cl;
};
```

In C++11, this can be easily done through *uniform-initialization*:

```
class Test
{
    public:
        Base cl{21};
//           ^^^^^^^
};
```

---

Footnote:

1: *The most vexing parse is a specific form of syntactic ambiguity resolution in the C++ programming language....* ~ Wikipedia

Comment: Very instructive, thanks... I didn't know about this famous funny "vexing parse" !?

Answer (score 3):

This is parsed as a function declaration, resulting in an error because the parameter should be a type:

```
Base cl(12);
```

You probably want a `Base` data member, initialized with the value `12`:

```
Base cl{12}; // requires C++11
```

If you don't have C++11 support, then you can initialize `cl` in `Test`'s constructor initialization list:

```
class Test
{
public:
  Test() : cl(12) {}
  Base cl;
};
```